# UIWebView in iOS 9 not printing the page

Tags: ios, printing, uiwebview, ios9

In example http://www.javascriptkit.com/howto/newtech2.shtml the button 'print this page' does print the page using a browser.

In order to print function javaScript window.print() is used.

I have opened that page using iPad iOS 9 via browser Safari. When pressing a button ' Print this Page' popup window is showing up with a print preview and a printer selection. 
Page is printing Ok, no issues.

So, I have written an application and added it into the UIWebView. And when I am opening that page using my application,  the 'print button' is not working.  The pop up window with page preview and printer selection is not showing up.

Could you help me,  point me in to the right direction,  how to print from iOS9 using UIWebView. Do I need to add some sort of additional classes?  Or printing option is not working at all in iOS 9 using UIWebView.

Thank you.